# How to deal with multiple tier templates with scripts in play framework 2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, template-engine

I have a template structure like this:

```
modal.scala.view

@()
  ... HTML code to display a modal in my app ...
```

---

```
foo.scala.view

@()
@scripts {
   ... The scripts required by foo.scala.view components ...
   ... The scripts required by modal.scala.view ... I want to avoid this!
}
@main(scripts){
   ... HTML code of foo ... 
   @modal
}
```

---

```
main.scala.view

@(scripts: Html)
... Main HTML code ...
@scripts
```

I would like to keep the scripts of modal in the modal.scala.view but I cant find a way to pass the scripts from the sub-template to the parent in order to render them in the correct place of the main template. Anyideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a canonical answer to your question that the Play team has blessed, but I can think of a couple of approaches: a monadic approach and an imperative approach.

**Wrap views in sub-controllers; encapsulate scripts in the output**

A large project I'm working on uses this strategy. We created a `MultipartHtml` type that contains `Html` output that should be contained in the document body and a type we created called `Resources` which contain stuff that should go elsewhere. We treat this type like a monad, so that we can `map` and `flatMap` it to manipulate the `Html` document content, while accumulating and deduplicating the `Resources`.

All of our controllers return `MultipartHtml`. They construct an instance from the results of the views and then simply `:+` `Resource` tags to the result. Our page-level controllers composite these pieces together. The core of what we do looks something like this:

```
/**
 * Output type for components to render body, head and end-of-body content
 * @param bodyMarkup the visual part of the component output
 * @param resources tags for content to include in the head or footer
 */
case class MultipartHtml(bodyMarkup: Html, resources: Seq[MultipartHtml.Resource] = Nil) {
  import com.huffpost.hyperion.lib.MultipartHtml._

  /**
   * Apply a transformation to the body content of this object
   * @param bodyMapper transformation function
   * @return a new object with transformed body content
   */
  def map(bodyMapper: Html => Html): MultipartHtml = MultipartHtml(bodyMapper(bodyMarkup), resources)

  /**
   * @param bodyMapper transformation function
   * @return the bodyMapper result combined with the component resource list
   */
  def flatMap(bodyMapper: Html => MultipartHtml): MultipartHtml = bodyMapper(bodyMarkup) ++ resources

  /**
   * Add a head and/or footer content to this object
   * @param resources the resources to add
   * @return a new object with the resource added
   */
  def ++(resources: GenTraversableOnce[Resource]): MultipartHtml = resources.foldLeft(this)(_ :+ _)

  /**
   * Add a head or footer content to this object
   * @param resource the resource to add
   * @return a new object with the resource added
   */
  def :+(resource: Resource): MultipartHtml = MultipartHtml(bodyMarkup, (resources :+ resource).distinct)

  /**
   * Prepend a head or footer content to this object
   * @param resource the resource to add
   * @return a new object with the resource added
   */
  def +:(resource: Resource): MultipartHtml = MultipartHtml(bodyMarkup, (resource +: resources).distinct)

  /** Get tags by resource type for injection into a template */
  def renderResourcesByType(resourceType: ResourceType): Html = Html(resources.filter(_.resourceType == resourceType).mkString("\n"))
}

/** Utility methods for MultipartHtml type */
object MultipartHtml {
  /** Empty MultipartHtml */
  def empty = MultipartHtml(Html(""))

  /** A resource that can be imported in the HTML head or footer*/
  trait ResourceType
  trait Resource {
    def resourceType: ResourceType
  }

  object HeadTag extends ResourceType
  object FooterTag extends ResourceType

  /** A style tag */
  case class StyleTag(styleUrl: String) extends Resource {
    val resourceType = HeadTag
    override def toString = {
      val assetUrl = routes.Assets.at(styleUrl).url
      s"""<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="$assetUrl">"""
    }
  }

  /** A script tag */
  case class ScriptTag(scriptUrl: String) extends Resource {
    val resourceType = FooterTag
    override def toString = {
      val assetUrl = routes.Assets.at(s"javascript/$scriptUrl").url
      s"""<script type="text/javascript" src="$assetUrl"></script>"""
    }
  }
}
```

There's a whole architecture built on top of this, but I probably shouldn't share too much, as it's an unreleased product.

**Create a helper that stores scripts in a mutable collection**

Another strategy might be to have your top level controller create an object that stores up the tags in a mutable data structure. I haven't tried this myself, but you could do something like:

```
import play.twirl.api.Html

case class TagStore(id: String) {
  val tags = scala.collection.mutable.Set[Html]()

  def addTag(tag: Html): Unit = {
    store += tag
  }
}
```

Then in your template, you could do:

```
@(addTag: Html => Unit)

@addTag {
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
}

@* Generate HTML *@
```

Downside here is that you have to forward this object down the line somehow, which could be a pain if your hierarchy of partial views can get deep.

Comment: Thanks acjay. I will try the imperative way because im working in java play. If it works I will be reporting the results here. Thanks again!

Comment: The mutable way works fine. And using implicits I was able to avoid littering all the templates with the mutable object. Thanks man.